# Comparing Unix Timestamp to datetime Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, unix, indexing

How would I be able to write a function where it shows the range of values where the unix timestamp `Unix` and `Dates` do not match, `Unix` and `Dates` are corelated. It will list all the consecutive mismatches in each row. So  `1444311750000` and `'2015-10-08 13:42:00'` do not match as well as the dates that continue up to `1634774520000` and `2021-10-21 00:07:00`

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 


def compare(datas):
    Unix = np.array(datas['Unix Timestamp'])
    Dates = np.array(datas['date'])
    
    Unix_pd = pd.to_datetime(Unix, unit='s', origin='unix')
    dates_pd = pd.to_datetime(dates)
    
    s = pd.Series(dates_pd.difference(Unix_pd))
    groups_diff_ne_1min = s.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)) != pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)
    groups = groups_diff_ne_1min.cumsum()
    result = s.groupby(groups).agg(['first', 'last', 'size'])
    print(result)


data = {'Unix Timestamp': [1444311600000, 1444311660000, 1444311750000, 1634774460000,
                           1634774520000, 1634774580000, 14443117200000], 
        'date': ['2015-10-08 13:40:00', '2015-10-08 13:41:00', '2015-10-08 13:42:00',
                '2021-10-21 00:05:00', '2021-10-21 00:07:00', '2021-10-21 00:03:00',
                '2021-10-21 01:13:00'],
```

Expected Output:

```
['2015-10-08 13:42:00 - 2021-10-21 00:07:00']
['2021-10-21 01:13:00']
```